# How to insert our own code into kernel source code

Tags: kernel

Can I able to modify the kernel of ubuntu OS,
If yes please share the steps to change.
or
Can I able to include my own code in kernel.

Comment: Sure, but... why do you want to modify the kernel? Kernel programming is a wide topic, and not something you learn in a Q&A site.

Comment: @vidarlo let's assume the OP has a good reason to do so, until proven otherwise... 

Comment: I'm perhaps assuming this is some kind of X-Y question :)

Answer (score 1):

You download the source code, add your modifications and then compile it.

To get the source code for the Ubuntu kernels, you can either do:

```
sudo apt install linux-source-<insert.kernel.version>
```

Or the following (if you have `deb-src` enabled in your repos):

```
sudo apt source linux-image-<insert.kernel.version>-generic
```

Adjust the commands for the kernel version you want.

After you have done your modifications, build and test the new kernel according to the [official documentation on the Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel).